# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in the creation of hibernate configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, exception, jboss

I'm working on a Hibernate project and I configured everything.

So, I generated the beans and hbm files.

Then, I wrote a test class to test the project(I used the `Client` class)

When I executed the code, the following exception was thrown:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.singleImplementationSanityCheck(LoggerFactory.java:192)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:113)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:269)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:255)
at org.aness.test.HiberM.<clinit>(HiberM.java:12)
Exception in thread "main"
```

the code is :

```
import org.aness.beans.*;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HiberM {
 final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Client.class);
public static void main(String[]arg){

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory sf =cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session s = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx =s.beginTransaction();

    Client c =new Client();
    c.setRaisonSociale("peugeot algerie");
    c.setNumeroRc("3215468897");
    c.setIdentificationFiscale("888777999");
    c.setAdresseActivite("blida zone atlas");
    c.setTelephone("00213(0)25436996");
    c.setFax("00213(0)25436996");

    s.save(c);
    tx.commit();

   }

 }
```

that's the whole problem.

the hibernate cfg file is : *

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory name="apurement">
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/apurement</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

the client mapping is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 27 d?c. 2012 11:47:54 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.aness.beans.Client" table="client" catalog="apurement">
    <id name="clientId" type="int">
        <column name="client_id" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="raisonSociale" type="string">
        <column name="raison_sociale" length="150" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="numeroRc" type="string">
        <column name="numero_rc" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="identificationFiscale" type="string">
        <column name="identification_fiscale" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="adresseActivite" type="string">
        <column name="adresse_activite" length="250" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="adressePersonelle" type="string">
        <column name="adresse_personelle" length="250" />
    </property>
    <property name="telephone" type="string">
        <column name="telephone" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="fax" type="string">
        <column name="fax" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="domiciliations" table="domiciliation" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="client_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="org.aness.beans.Domiciliation" />
    </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Please post your hibernate.cfg.xml and your Client.hbm.xml file. Also, which Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: Do you have a hibernate.cfg.xml file? Did you try a different version of slf4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've hit [this issue](http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/slf4j-dev/2009-December/002807.html).

It seems you're using SLF4J version 1.5.8 (or thereabouts), as the [source code of `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` with tag 'SLF4J_1.5.8'](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/SLF4J_1.5.8/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.java) has line numbers that match those in your stacktrace.

I would recommend updating to later version of SLF4J.

Comment: i did but nothing happends

Comment: @AnisBouchenafa: which version of SLF4J are you now using?

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities :

Your `Hibernate.cfg.xml` is not on classpath. What folder is it in?

Else you may try updating the version of `slf4j` jar