# Hibernate SessionFactory is giving java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to create a sessionfactory but whenever the control goes to NewHibernateUtil.java it throws java.lang.ExceptionInitializeError

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found

This is how I am calling the NewHibernateUtil:

```
SessionFactory sessionfactory = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
```

And this is my code for NewHiberNateUtil:

```
public class NewHibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the above code.

Comment: This might be configuration problem(libraries incompatibility). Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054245/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-in-the-creation-of-hibernate-configuration

Comment: I believe that your hibernate.cfg.xml path is incorrect. Verify location of hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like configuration problem. U can post your config file and exception message in detail here for more clear idea...

Cheers!